# alljoyn repository, 502 bad gateway

Tags: alljoyn

I'm getting to stackoverflow after visiting https://ask.allseenalliance.org/questions/

I cannot access to https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/core/
The page reports 502 Bad Gateway error and X.509 certificate has expired on 12/03/2018 and has not been renewed.

Is the Alljoyn project dead or the code repository has been moved to other location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allseen Alliance no longer exists as an entity. It was merged with [Open Connectivity Foundation (OCF)](https://openconnectivity.org/developer/reference-implementation/alljoyn). You can find the source code on the [AllJoyn Open Source Project GitHub page](https://github.com/alljoyn).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This perfectly answer my question

Comment: It was too ambitious, over-engineered. I worked with it back in 2015 and you could feel it already, it would never take off...